# Sending cardholder name to Authorize.net through API without billing address

Tags: api, authorize.net

I'm trying to find out how to send cardholder name without sending billing address to Authorize.net in order to get it populated under "Customer" column. With old AIM integration method cardholder name was part of credit card information but it sounds like new API only accepting it as part of "bill to"? Something doesn't make sense to me. Any suggestions?
Note: I'm not creating customer profiles
[image]

Comment: What exactly doesn't make sense to you?

Answer (score 0):

Simply set *firstname* and *lastname* only under *billTo* block.

[image]